# How can I fit bounds on a geojson I load with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

I'm loading a route from a geojson file with Leaflet-ajax, and I can't figure out how to set the bounds of my map to the route.

This code gives me an error of `Uncaught Error: Bounds are not valid.`:

```js
L.tileLayer(' ... ', { ... }).addTo(map_of_route);
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("my_json.json");
geojsonLayer.addTo(map_of_route);
map_of_route.fitBounds(geojsonLayer.getBounds());
```

(extraneous map layer stuff removed for readability)

Comment: See answer here; maybe relevant? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/305231/101540

Comment: After some finnagling, the answer there did the trick